# Looking for a way to assign a value with ternary but with no else condition

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have this statement below in my html element. Is there a way to only assign the first part and not have the null part. So basically, if the condition is true set the value to '' otherwise do nothing.

```
[value]="ceModal.industryId !== 'Item185' ? '' : null"
```

I tried

```
[value]="ceModal.industryId !== 'Item185' ?? ''"
```

but this throws an error

Here is the whole input tag

```html
<input 
  type="text" 
  class="form-control" 
  placeholder="ex. Other industry info" 
  [(ngModel)]="ceModal.industryOther" 
  name="ceIndustryOther" 
  [disabled]="ceModal.industryId !== 'Item185'" 
  [value]="ceModal.industryId !== 'Item185' ? '' : null"
>
```

Comment: Does "otherwise do nothing" mean "don't do an assignment"?

Comment: Yes. If the value is 'Item185' don't do anything, leave the value (whatever it is) alone.

Comment: What is `value` here? Is it an input property?

Comment: I just updated my post with the complete element tag. With the else part setting to null, it works fine in the UI, but it doesn't set the value in the backside (.ts file)

Comment: Have you tried undefined? Also I wonder: why are you setting value and ngModel at the same time? Doesn't ngModel "control" the value attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please, if use  `[(ngModel)]`, not use `[value]` it's not logic (*), split `[(ngModel)]` in `[ngModel]` and `(ngModelChange)`

```
<input [ngModel]="ceModal.industryOther" 
       (ngModelChange)="ceModal.industryOther=$event==''?null:$event">
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p7tamb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

(*) you are saying to Angular that the value is a variable with the [ngModel], and the value to show is another thing with [value]

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="ex. Other industry info" 
       [(ngModel)]="ceModal.industryOther" name="ceIndustryOther" 
       [disabled]="ceModal.industryId !== 'Item185'" 
       [value]="ceModal.industryId !== 'Item185' ? '' : ceModal.industryOther">
```

I think that the value of `industryOther` would be kept as it is if `ceModal.industryId !== 'Item185'`. Is that what you want?

Comment: at first attempt this looks like it makes the correct changes in the UI, but it doesn't change the value of ceModal.industryOther. So if I have a value, say 'test' then change the value, effectively setting the value to '' and then save. In my .ts file there is no change to the value. So if I refresh the page, the 'test' still is visible.

Comment: When you say *"In my .ts file there is no change to the value"*, you mean `ceModal.industryOther` isn't changing to whatever is passed to `[value]` at all?

Comment: It means that, when the industryId is 'Item185' I see the UI go blank. Good! But when I save the form, I put a break point in the .ts file where I take the ceModal with all the form values and set it to another model value. I look to see if the industryOther value has been changed to '' and it hasn't

Comment: Oh... It's been a while since I used template-driven directives, but it makes sense. It looks like `ngModel` data-binding is executed after `value` has been settle, so overriding it. Basically it's cannot be used in a control that already has a `ngModel`

Comment: This is a very simple [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mjykmr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) to exemplify it

Comment: I know I can set the value in the .ts file with a ngChange=something() method I'm just trying to avoid doing anything in the .ts file.